# How can I create a Weak<dyn T> via Weak::new()?

Tags: rust, observer-pattern, weak-references

I am working on a pub/sub model that looks like this:

```
trait EventObserver { ... }

struct Publisher {
    observer: Mutex<Weak<dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync>>,
}
```

How do I initialize the `Publisher` with a `Weak` set to nothing?

If I write it like this:

```
impl Publisher {
    pub fn new() -> Publisher {
        Publisher {
            observer: Mutex::new(Weak::new()),
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:12:34
   |
12 |             observer: Mutex::new(Weak::new()),
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the struct `Weak`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Unsize<dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync>`
   = note: required for the cast from `std::sync::Weak<_>` to `std::sync::Weak<(dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync + 'static)>`
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
12 |             observer: Mutex::new(Weak::<T>::new()),
   |                                      +++++
```

And if I specify the type is `dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync`, the compiler says:

```
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `new` exists for struct `Weak<dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:12:75
   |
3  | trait EventObserver {}
   | ------------------- doesn't satisfy `dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync: Sized`
...
12 |             observer: Mutex::new(Weak::<dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync>::new()),
   |                                                                           ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Weak<dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn EventObserver + Send + Sync: Sized`
```

I am just looking for a way to initialize the `Weak` to nothing, so it's expected that any upgrade of the `observer` will fail to find a valid pointer. After `subscribe()` is called, then the later upgrade of the `Weak` can succeed.

I do know two workarounds, one is to use `Option` to wrap the Weak, another is to create a struct that impl the trait. Is there a clean way just to initialize the `Weak<dyn T + Send + Sync>` to nothing compared to these workarounds?

Comment: Interesting that `Weak::new` doesn't have `T: ?Sized` like most of its other methods. Such so that it makes me think its intentional. Could be that its unclear how invalid fat pointers should be created since `Weak` uses `usize::MAX` as a sentinel address to represent the non-linked state from `new`.

Comment: I just saw this link: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-cant-weak-new-be-used-with-a-trait-object/29976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Weak::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.Weak.html#method.new) doesn't have a `?Sized` bound, so this cannot be done naturally. The fix is to create a `Weak` of a type that implement the trait. If you don't have such type accessible, you can create such type that just panics in all methods (since they'll never be called anyway).

For example:

```rust
impl Publisher {
    pub fn new() -> Publisher {
        let publisher = Publisher {
            observer: Mutex::new(Weak::<SomeTypeImplementingEventObserver>::new()),
        };
        publisher
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me think. Typically the publisher will call `observer.update_info` right? If the implementation panics, is that good? Or are you saying they'll never be called?

Comment: @OLNG To call the method on a `Weak`, you need to `upgrade()` it. Upgrading a `Weak` grabbed via `Weak::new()` will always fail (return `None`), so it is not possible to call any method on it.

Comment: Got it, today I learned